# How to stop text overlapping icon and keep text vertically centered when wrapping, using Bootstrap 5 buttons in a flex box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5 button code with `horizontally and vertically centered text` and a `right aligned` icon with multiple buttons in a `flex box` situation, how do I stop the button text overlapping the icon when it wraps, keep the icon `vertically centered` when the button text wraps, and keep the button text `vertically center aligned` when it wraps?

You can see whole code with the wrapping and overlapping issues in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SquareGiraffe/2xdf8y7b/15/) by moving the center column with your mouse and making the display area bigger and smaller.

```css
.custom-btn,
.custom-btn:visited {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5rem 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
  flex: 33%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  height: 70px;
}

.custom-btn:active,
.custom-btn:hover {
  background-color: #7d7c7c;
  border-color: #787878;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon-arrow-new {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  width: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn custom-btn">This Section<img src="https://svgshare.com/i/fPK.svg" class="icon-arrow-new" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to accomplish this but I think following changes will get you what you are after.

Increase `.custom-btn` left/right padding to a larger number (Ex. 2.2rem) to clear the arrow and use flex properties to center the text vertically and horizontally:

```
.custom-btn, .custom-btn:visited {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5rem 2.2rem; /* Increase left/right padding */
  margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  line-height: 1.2rem;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
  flex: 33%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  /* Add flex properties */
  display: flex;  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle forked from OP's fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/fd8ru69h](https://jsfiddle.net/fd8ru69h)

Comment: Your display property rule will be overridden by Bootstrap. I suggest copying the snippet down here to demonstrate your solution live.

Comment: The OP provided a jsfiddle which I forked to show my answer.  This way you can actually resize the window to see the result, which you can't do by using a snippet here.

Comment: Sure you can. Use the full screen mode and open your dev tools with F12. It's a great way to work in general.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a full flex (inline-flex) layout. Part of the problem is that some of your custom style rules were being overwritten by Bootstrap. I've added a second class to the selectors to increase specificity.

```css
.btn.custom-btn,
.btn.custom-btn:visited {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 33%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5rem 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
  border-color: #c1c1c1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  height: 70px;
}

.btn.custom-btn:active,
.btn.custom-btn:hover {
  background-color: #7d7c7c;
  border-color: #787878;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon-arrow-new {
  width: 22px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn custom-btn">
  <span>This Section</span>
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/fPK.svg" class="icon-arrow-new" />
</a>

<a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn custom-btn">
  <span>This<br>Section</span>
  <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/fPK.svg" class="icon-arrow-new" />
</a>
```